# How do I get the selected row's attributes from NSArrayController and Core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a table on my that's hooked up to an NSArrayController. I know how to hook the bindings up and control drag to the arraycontroller's delete action. But what I need to do is to get a specific attribute from the selected row on the table, from core data, and perform and delete that row if certain conditions are meant. I've also got the delete part down.

I'm able to get the selected row:

```
NSUInteger packageIndex = [self.packagesTableView selectedRow];
    NSArray *selectedObjects = [[self.meteorPakcagesArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:packageIndex];
    NSLog(@"pckg: %@", selectedObjects);
```

And in the log I get:

```
2014-02-15 08:01:43.067 Orbit[10320:303] pckg: <MeteorPackage: 0x6080000adaa0> (entity: MeteorPackage; id: 0x608000221060 <x-coredata://7BDCF290-6A40-4BAD-A8BE-5819CCB99DEA/MeteorPackage/p118> ; data: {
    name = "preserve-inputs";
    project = "0x608000220fe0 <x-coredata://7BDCF290-6A40-4BAD-A8BE-5819CCB99DEA/Project/p116>";
    type = meteor;
})
```

But I can't figure out how to get a specific attribute from the array. I want to get the name and the type. I've tried pulling the data out like this:

```
MeteorPackage *pckg = [selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"pckg: %@", pckg);
```

But I get the following error:

```
-[MeteorPackage objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080002a1aa0
```

I'm clearly making a rookie mistake because I'm new to objective-c and core data. So how do I get those attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this

```
NSArray *selectedObjects = [[self.meteorPakcagesArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:packageIndex];
NSLog(@"pckg: %@", selectedObjects);
```

with this

```
MeteorPackage *selectedPackage = [[self.meteorPakcagesArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:packageIndex];
NSLog(@"pckg: %@", selectedPackage);
```

because the objectAtIndex method already returns your MeteorPackage object... not an array